# Changing variables within arrays for a table

Tags: python, arrays

I was following a tutorial for programming a table, but it affected the way the elements of an array change whenever an input is used.

The tickets start at 480, and there are 7 arrays of this.

I want it so that whenever an input is put in, the variable changes in the array.

This is how it's organized:

```py
UpTimes = [9,11,13,15]
UpTickets = [480,480,480,480]
UpMoneyMade = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

DownTimes = [10,12,14,16]
DownTickets = [480,480,480,640]
DownMoneyMade = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0]
```

And this Is how I displayed it:

```py
Board = [[UpTimes[0],UpTickets[0],UpMoneyMade[0]],
         [DownTimes[0],DownTickets[0],DownMoneyMade[0]],
         [UpTimes[1],UpTickets[1],UpMoneyMade[1]],
         [DownTimes[1],DownTickets[1],DownMoneyMade[1]],
         [UpTimes[2],UpTickets[2],UpMoneyMade[2]],
         [DownTimes[2],DownTickets[2],DownMoneyMade[2]],
         [UpTimes[3],UpTickets[3],UpMoneyMade[3]],
         [DownTimes[3],DownTickets[3],DownMoneyMade[3]],]

for item in Board:
    print("|",item[0]," "*(10-len(str(item[0]))), "|", item[1], " "*14, "|", item[2], " "*12, "|")
```

And it displays like this:

```
| Train Times |  Available Tickets |  Money Collected |
| 9           | 480                | 0.0              |
| 10          | 480                | 0.0              |
| 11          | 480                | 0.0              |
| 12          | 480                | 0.0              |
| 13          | 480                | 0.0              |
| 14          | 480                | 0.0              |
| 15          | 480                | 0.0              |
| 16          | 640                | 0.0              |
```

I can't change the variable anymore, but this seems like the most efficient way to present a table.

Does anyone have a fix to this?

Comment: which language do you use?

Comment: @YochaiAkoka from the syntax i would conclude this is python

Comment: this is python, yeah.